# Filter deeply nested array of objects using map() and filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the below nested data array. I would like to filter on the second level of children leaving only the children that have a name of either "Assistant" or "Advisor" while keeping the rest of the underlying data structure the same.

```
data = [{
  "name": "root",
  "median": 60000.0,
  "children": [{
      "name": "Defence",
      "median": 60000.0,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 30000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 50000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Secretary",
          "median": 60000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Administrator",
          "median": 60000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 20000.0,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Healthcare",
      "median": 60000,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Manager",
          "median": 80000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 60000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Legal",
          "median": 20000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Cashier",
          "median": 30000,
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

The desired outcome leaves the upper level children the same while returning the second level children that match "Assistant" and "Advisor".

```
data = [{
  "name": "root",
  "median": 60000.0,
  "children": [{
      "name": "Defence",
      "median": 60000.0,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 30000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 50000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 20000.0,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Healthcare",
      "median": 60000,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 60000,
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

I have tried to use a combination of `map()` and `filter()` but it only returns the matching second level children.

```
var fmatch = ["Assistant", "Advisor"]
console.log(data.map(c=> c.children.map(c => c.children.filter(c => fmatch.includes(c.name)))))
```

```js
data = data = [{
  "name": "root",
  "median": 60000.0,
  "children": [{
      "name": "Defence",
      "median": 60000.0,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 30000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 50000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Secretary",
          "median": 60000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Administrator",
          "median": 60000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 20000.0,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Healthcare",
      "median": 60000,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Manager",
          "median": 80000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 60000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Legal",
          "median": 20000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Cashier",
          "median": 30000,
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

var fmatch = ["Assistant", "Advisor"]
console.log(data.map(c=> c.children.map(c => c.children.filter(c => fmatch.includes(c.name)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `forEach` loop when you're looking to modify the underlying data structure. All `Array.prototype.map()` does is return a new array based on the criteria provided.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
data = data = [{
  "name": "root",
  "median": 60000.0,
  "children": [{
      "name": "Defence",
      "median": 60000.0,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 30000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 50000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Secretary",
          "median": 60000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Administrator",
          "median": 60000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 20000.0,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Healthcare",
      "median": 60000,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Manager",
          "median": 80000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 60000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Legal",
          "median": 20000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Cashier",
          "median": 30000,
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

var fmatch = ["Assistant", "Advisor"]
data.forEach(c => {
    c.children.forEach(c => {
        c.children = c.children.filter(c => fmatch.includes(c.name))
    })
})
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a simple loop to iterate each parent and only use filter when needed.

If you still want to use `.map()` you would need to return the full objects instead of the filtered array only

```js
data = [{
  "name": "root",
  "median": 60000.0,
  "children": [{
      "name": "Defence",
      "median": 60000.0,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 30000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 50000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Secretary",
          "median": 60000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Administrator",
          "median": 60000.0,
        },
        {
          "name": "Assistant",
          "median": 20000.0,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Healthcare",
      "median": 60000,
      "children": [{
          "name": "Manager",
          "median": 80000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Advisor",
          "median": 60000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Legal",
          "median": 20000,
        },
        {
          "name": "Cashier",
          "median": 30000,
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

var fmatch = ["Assistant", "Advisor"];

const filteredData = data;
filteredData.forEach(item => {
  item.children.forEach(firstChild => {
    firstChild.children = firstChild.children.filter(c => fmatch.includes(c.name));
  });
});

console.log(filteredData);
```